# An script/Plugin for automatic page creation per term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pages, automation, plugin-polylang

My site is such that it introduces the devices and displays their specifications (something like WooCommerce but without the ability to buy), I have 2 Post-Types named "Devices" and "Companies" where all the devices and companies are located in the respective sections, which are connected to their respective terms; I have 3 terms named Device, Company, and Service. These 3 terms link these post-types to each other (or maybe there is a more optimal way, but I don't know). My questions are:

Is it possible that there is no need to create a Post_type anymore? I use JetEngine and save all the information and parameters of each device in my Term so that I can use it in Elementor.
Is there a plugin that can automatically create a Post_type for each relevant term (along with some custom fields automatically)? For example, if I create something called Microsoft in Term Company, the plugin will automatically create a page in Post_type Companies. In addition, my site is in two languages (Persian and English), and I use the PolyLang plugin, and because of this, my work has become more difficult, because I have to manually create a page for each term in Post_Type, that too Along with Custom Fields related to that language! If you provide a script, please explain how to use it because I don't know much.
there were no plugins I could be able to find for this situation.